# Excel VBA forcing selection of objects after run

Tags: excel, focus, multiple-instances, vba

I've researched this to death and feel like I'm the only person it's ever happened to.

I have some VBA that:

- Creates a copy of 3 sheets to a new wb
- In the new wb converts to values, deletes objects (shapes and controls) and all but 3 ranges
- Opens an existing third file and sets the contents of three ranges in that to match the new wb
- Closes the existing file (saved)
- Closes the new wb (saved)
- Gives a message box saying complete

At the end of all this, something weird happens with the state of the windows. The selected cell does not appear selected. If I try and click a control afterwards, it selects the object (hence users could drag them). It shouldn't and this is the big problem.

I've tried selecting a cell through code, it throws an error. I had limited success by forcing drawing mode off using `Call CommandBars("Drawing").Controls("Select Objects").Execute` and activating a specific sheet & selecting a cell. However, even then if I even click on a few cells afterwards, the next time I select a control it will select it as an object rather than click the thing.

I have no idea why and can't find anyone who's seen this before.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks,

Basil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure it out entirely, but I did find a fix. Hopefully it works for anyone else who finds this problem.

At the end of the code I added this:
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("ctrlExportPrices").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Select

So it forced a control on the sheet to be selected, and then a cell.

The next time I select the control manually, it clicks it rather than selecting the drawing object.